# Cancelling repeated crackling noise from microphone

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone, audio-recording

Regardless of which microphone I use, whenever I connect them to the microphone jack of my computer, there's always this repeated crackling noise on it. Here's a sample I recorded with sonic visualizer on almost complete silence.

[image]

The yellow peaks are the crackling.

What I have currently tried was to go to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and add the following lines at the end of the file:

```
.ifexists module-echo-cancel.so
load-module module-echo-cancel aec_method=webrtc source_name=echocancel sink_name=echocancel1
set-default-source echocancel
set-default-sink echocancel1
.endif
```

The issue with this is that it added a noise cancel channel to my webcam's microphone and not the actual one that I use.

How do I specify the right device to the echo cancel module? I am also open to alternative solutions.

Comment: I retracted my close vote.